# OOP: return an object with multiple properties and use the values in another function

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I want to use a getDOM method to collect the DOM values.
The getDOM() function returns an object with key value pairs (the values of the input DOM).

I want to use the getDOM object in another method called tempDifference().
This is not working:

*app2.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inputHeatFlow' of undefined
    at Object.tempDifference (app2.js:30)
    at :1:24*

```js
// create app as object
var calcHeatFlow = {
    // collect DOM information
    getDOM: function() {
        // return DOM information as object
        return {
            // return getDOM properties with DOM values
            inputHeatFlow: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input__flow").value),
            inputHeatReturn: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input__return").value),
            inputHeatTemp: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input__temp").value),
            inputHeatExponent: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input__exponent").value),
            inputHeatValue: parseFloat(document.getElementById("input__value").value)
        }
    },
    // structure calculate methods
    calculate: {
        // calculate fixed value 
        fixedValue: function() {
            const normHeatFlow = 75, normHeatReturn = 65, normTemp = 20;
            
            return (normHeatFlow - normHeatReturn) / 
                    (Math.log((normHeatFlow - normTemp) / 
                    (normHeatReturn - normTemp)));
                
        },
        // calculate temperature difference
        tempDifference: function() {

            // return a value
            return (this.getDOM.inputHeatFlow - this.getDOM.inputHeatReturn) / 
                   (Math.log((this.getDOM.inputHeatFlow - this.getDOM.inputHeatTemp) / 
                   (this.getDOM.inputHeatReturn - this.getDOM.inputHeatTemp)));
        },
        // use fixedValue and tempDifference to calculate the result
        result: function() {
            // calculate result
        }
    }
};

// collect DOM information in execution phase
calcHeatFlow.getDOM();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Wärmeleistungsrechner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">

        <form class="input">
            <input type="number" id="input__flow"  value="100">
            <input type="number" id="input__return" value="80">
            <input type="number" id="input__temp" value="20">
            <input type="number" id="input__exponent" value="1.2836">
            <input type="number" id="input__value" value="2103">
        </form>
        <div class="output">
            <div id="output__result">
                Result
            </div>
            <div id="output__history">
                History
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="btn">Go</button>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a JS beginner and I try to understand OOP. Every explanation is appreciated!

Thanks, Josef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of `this` in `calcHeatFlow.calculate.tempDifference` is incorrect. If you call the function as

```
calcHeatFlow.calculate.tempDifference()
```

`this` refers to `calcHeatFlow.calculate` which doesn't have a `getDOM` property and hence the error report: `this.getDOM` is undefined and can't have any properties.

---

In addition `getDOM` is a function, and needs to be called to pick up input values. Depending on final object design, `getDOM` could return parsed input values, store them as individual properties of  the `calcHeatFlow` object, or store the object it returns  as a property of `calcHeatFlow`.

Functions using the results of a call to `getDOM` must either call it or use values from the last time it was called (if they were saved).

Some redesign of object structure is called for. Storing different calculation functions as properties of `calculate` may be good for self documenting code, but it may be easier to make them properties of `getDOM` if they use `this` to refer to the `calcHeatFlow` object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `getDOM` is defined as a function that returns an object not as an object -  this means that you need to invoke this function in order to get access to this object, to do that you will need to replace all of:

```
this.getDOM.someProperty
```

With:

```
this.getDOM().someProperty
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working unless I comment the object **calculate** out. 

How does it work without commenting my parent object out?

Comment: Because with **calculate** you're probably accessing your properties like this: `calcHeatFlow.calculate.tempDifference()` which changes your `this` context from `calHeatFlow` to `calculate` and you lose your access, look into ES6 classes or ES5 module pattern if you want to learn how to structure your code correctly in an OO way